# assign variable only if it is null

Tags: kotlin

on Ruby one have something like this:

```
@var ||= 'value'
```

basically, it means that `@var` will be assigned `'value'` only if `@var` is not assigned yet (e.g. if `@var` is `nil`)

I'm looking for the same on Kotlin, but so far, the closest thing would be the elvis operator. Is there something like that and I missed the documentation?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [lazy](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html#lazy)?

Comment: hmm, not really...I mean, in my case, I want to assign a `uid` on a `prePersist` JPA hook and I thought that maybe Kotlin had an elegant way instead check if `uid` is null and assign

Comment: I guess `value = value ?: newValue` is indeed the shortest way.

Comment: that can work...thanks! would you mind to move it to an answer so I can accept?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The shortest way I can think of is indeed using the elvis operator:

```
value = value ?: newValue
```

If you do this often, an alternative is to use a [delegated property](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegated-properties.html), which only stores the value if its `null`:

```
class Once<T> {

    private var value: T? = null

    operator fun getValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>): T? {
        return value
    }

    operator fun setValue(thisRef: Any?, property: KProperty<*>, value: T?) {
        this.value = this.value ?: value
    }
}
```

You can now create a property that uses this like so:

```
var value by Once<String>()

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(value) // 'null'
    value = "1"
    println(value) // '1'
    value = "2"
    println(value) // '1'
}
```

Note that this is not thread-safe and does not allow setting back to `null`. Also, this does evaluate the `new` expression while the simple elvis operator version might not.

Comment: You probably want `class Once<T: Any>`. Otherwise you could use `var value by Once<String?>` which would be confusing.

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom Why is that? It accepts nullable types now, but in usage there's no difference, right?

Comment: I guess it wouldn't make any difference. I was thinking in terms of the `NotNull` delegate for some reason. Couldn't tell you why.

Answer (score 1):

Other way we could do it is by using `ifEmpty`..

From the docs: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/if-empty.html

Usage:

```
val empty = ""

val emptyOrNull: String? = empty.ifEmpty { null }
println(emptyOrNull) // null

val emptyOrDefault = empty.ifEmpty { "default" }
println(emptyOrDefault) // default

val nonEmpty = "abc"
val sameString = nonEmpty.ifEmpty { "def" }
println(sameString) // abc
```

**EDIT:**
Seems like this does not work if the initial value is `NULL` and only for strings..