# How can I make this singleton simpler in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

How can I make this singleton simpler in Kotlin for the Android room database initialization?

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Book::class, User::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun bookModel() : BookDao
    abstract fun userModel() : UserDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInMemoryDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            if (INSTANCE == null) {
                INSTANCE = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java).build()
            }
            return INSTANCE!!
        }

        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an array literal (`[]`) instead of `arrayOf` and you can use the elvis operator for the null check. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315778/assign-variable-only-if-it-is-null).

```
@Database(entities = [Book::class, User::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun bookModel() : BookDao
    abstract fun userModel() : UserDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInMemoryDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase { 
            INSTANCE = INSTANCE ?: Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java).build()
            return INSTANCE!!
        }
    
        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }
}
```

Since you need the instance you have to save it somewhere, using a `companion object` seems like a reasonable solution to me.

If you somehow don't want to save the intance inside `AppDatabase`, you can also use an object (which is a singleton in Kotlin).

```
object AppDatabaseProvider {
    private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

    fun getInMemoryDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
       // ...
    }

    fun destroyInstance() {
        INSTANCE = null
    }
}
```

These are both options to deal with static data in Kotlin, but you won't get it much shorter than that.

Answer (score 1):

Your solution is basically fine as is.

Using an array literal is an option, as it's been pointed out by @Willi Mentzel, it makes your code a bit shorter, if you like how it looks.

However, this code for getting the singleton instance is wrong:

```
private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

fun getInMemoryDatabase(context: Context) = INSTANCE ?: Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java).build()
```

The `getInMemoryDatabase` function never *assigns* a value to `INSTANCE`, meaning it will forever be `null`, and every time the function is called, the right hand side of the Elvis operator will be evaluated and returned. This means a new instance every time - instead of having a singleton, you're just creating a factory with this code.

---

You *could* use the Elvis operator to shorten your original code a bit:

```
fun getInMemoryDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
    INSTANCE = INSTANCE ?: Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java).build()
    return INSTANCE!!
}
```

This will do an extra assignment of `INSTANCE` to itself every call after the first one though, and I'd argue that saving those couple lines might not be worth it, as your original code with just a regular null check was easier to read than this is.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake! :) I also think, you won't get it much shorter as nhaarman also showed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44315778/assign-variable-only-if-it-is-null

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be any advance, try as follow

```
@Database(entities = arrayOf(Book::class, User::class), version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun bookModel() : BookDao
    abstract fun userModel() : UserDao

    companion object {
        private var INSTANCE: AppDatabase? = null

        fun getInMemoryDatabase(context: Context): AppDatabase {
            return INSTANCE ?: Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, this).build()
        }

        fun destroyInstance() {
            INSTANCE = null
        }
    }
}
```